# Binding on a copied message

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have a function to copy an email message in a sub-folder, also applying a category in case of multiple attachments.

```
void CopyInSubfolder(EmailMessage email, bool categorize)
{
    PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.ParentFolderId);
    Item item = email.Copy(_subFolder);
    EmailMessage copiedMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, propSet);
    if (categorize)
        copiedMessage.SetCategory("MULTIPLE ATTACHMENTS");
}
```

being `SetCategory` a simple extension method:

```
public static void SetCategory(this EmailMessage pContainer, string pCategory)
{
    StringList ExistingCategories = pContainer.Categories;
    if(!ExistingCategories.Contains(pCategory))
    { 
        ExistingCategories.Add(pCategory);
    }
    pContainer.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run the `SetCategory` method on the `CopiedMessage` item, I always get an empty `StringList` object, no matter how many existing categories the message already has. If I try and call the method on the original message it works as intended, so I guess I'm having trouble binding to the copied message. I used [this how-to article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600291(v=exchg.150).aspx) for the copying part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.ParentFolderId)
```

in

```
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Categories)
```

I thought binding would bind the new object to the **whole** item, but I guess that's not how it works.